# Three bases, one linear map, find vector $x$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Given three bases $B, C$ and $D$ and linear map $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$, and $x$ from $\Bbb R^2$. We also know that $[x]_B=(x_1,x_2)^T$.

$$[f]_{B\to C}=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 3 \\3 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$[f]_{D\to C}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 3 \\-1 & 5 \end{bmatrix}$$

Find $x$ in $D$ with respect to $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: "from $B$ to $D$" is equivalent to "from $B$ to $C$ AND from $C$ to $D$".
You know how to go from $B$ to $C$. You also know how to go from $D$ to $C$... so, ¿How to do the inverse walk?

Comment: the inverse is 1/8  \begin{bmatrix}5 & -3 \\1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} . But is f necessarily identity?

Comment: Because if f is identity you can just generate x in D by multiplying [f]C→D [f]B→C x in B. Which would be   \begin{bmatrix}1/8 & 3/2 \\5/8 & 1/2 \end{bmatrix} -> (1/8x1 + 3/2x2; 5/8x1 + 1/2x2)T.

Comment: Ok is the answer: $[x]_D=(1/8 x_1 + 3/2 x_2 ,5/8 x_1 + 1/2 x_2)^T$ ?

Comment: Yes @JanLhoták, correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$[f]_{D\to C}=\begin{bmatrix}1&3\\-1&5\end{bmatrix}\implies [f^{-1}]_{C\to D}=\begin{bmatrix}1&3\\-1&5\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$$

$v=[f]_{B\to C}x$ gives you the image of $x$ under $f$ with respect to basis $C$. $[f^{-1}]_{C\to D}v$ gives you the vector in $\Bbb R^2$ with respect to basis $D$ whose image under $f$ is $v$ with respect to basis $C$; in other words, the representation of $x$ in $D$.

$$[x]_D=\begin{bmatrix}1&3\\-1&5\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}2 & 3 \\3 & 1 \end{bmatrix}[x]_B=\frac18\begin{bmatrix}1&12\\5&4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}$$